# C++ call by reference - graph adjacency lists

Tags: c++, graph-theory

i'm following a C++ course in which is requested to create a graph using adjacency list method and perform some operations on it.

I'm still in the first part creating the graph.

I have a vector of pointers, hope it is well declared, which has all the same value after the function graph::PopulateGraph finishes. When I try to access them, for example i'm debugging g.head(1), the run terminates with return value different from 0.

I think something is wrong in the function call so everything works good until we're talking with local variable but then the variable are not modified and coming back to global variables nothing exists anymore.

Could you please take a look to the code?

```
/*Objective: 

Write a set of constructors for declaring and initializing a graph. 
An edge will have a positive cost that is its distance. Have a procedure that produces a randomly generated set of edges with positive distances. 
Assume the graphs are undirected. The random graph procedure should have edge density as a parameter and distance range as a parameter.
So a graph whose density is 0.1 would have 10% of its edges picked at random and its edge distance would be selected at random from the distance range. 
The procedure should run through all possible undirected edges, say (i,j) and place the edge in the graph if a random probability calculation is less 
than the density. 
Compute for a set of randomly generated graphs an average shortest path.

Printout of program, 200 words on what you learned, and output showing the average path length calculation. 
Use densities: 20% and 40% on a graph of 50 nodes with a distance range of 1.0 to 10.0.   To get an average path length, compute the 49 paths:

1 to 2, 1 to 3, 1 to 4, …, 1 to 50. 

*/




#include <stdio.h>     
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>

#define DEBUG

using namespace std;



typedef struct AdjVertex{
    int value;
    double cost;
    AdjVertex* next;
}AdjVertex;


double prob(){
    
    return (static_cast<double> (rand())/RAND_MAX);
}


class graph{
    
    int size;
    public :
        
    AdjVertex **head;
    AdjVertex* AddNewVertex(int value, int weight, AdjVertex* head); 
    AdjVertex* PopulateGraph(   AdjVertex *head,int pos,int size, double P);
   
//Constructor

    graph(int N)  {
        // allocate new node
        head = new AdjVertex*[N];
        this->size = N;
        // initialize head pointer for all vertices
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
            head[i] = NULL;
        }
    
    
    };
    
    //Function that add a new node to the graph
    AdjVertex* graph::AddNewVertex(int value, int weight, AdjVertex* head)   {
    if(weight>0){
        
        #ifdef DEBUG
        cout << "I'm generating a new node with label "<< value <<endl;
        #endif
        
        AdjVertex* newNode = new AdjVertex;
        newNode->value = value;
        newNode->cost = weight;
        newNode->next = head;   // point new node to current head
        return newNode;
        }else{
        return head;
        }
    }
    
    //Function PopulateGraph set Non-existence for E(i,i) edges and randomly generate E(i,j) edges based on probability P, setting on existing edges random cost between 1.0 and 10.0;
    AdjVertex* graph::PopulateGraph(AdjVertex *head,int pos,int size, double P){
        
        #ifdef DEBUG
        cout << "I'm filling adjiacency list of vertex"<< pos<<endl;
        #endif
        
        for (int j=0;j<size;++j){
            bool X=prob()<P;
            
                if(pos==j){     //if the edges is on the same vertex, we do not want loops.         
                    #ifdef DEBUG
                    cout << "I'm avoiding a loop"<<endl;
                    #endif
                    }else{
                    
                    head=AddNewVertex(j,X,head); //*CreateCost(1.0,10.0)
                    }
                }
    }
            
    
    
void display_AdjList(AdjVertex* ptr, int i)
{
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        cout << "(" << i << ", " << ptr->value
            << ", " << ptr->cost << ") ";
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}   
    
    
    
    
    int main(){
    
    int SIZE=4;
    
    graph G(SIZE);
    
    
    
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; ++i){ 
            #ifdef DEBUG
             cout << "I'm starting to fill a new list"<<endl;
            #endif
                
           G.head[i]=G.PopulateGraph(G.head[i],i,SIZE,0.5);
           //double x=prob()<0.2 ;
           //cout << x << "" <<endl;
           
        }   
    #ifdef DEBUG
     cout << "I finished to populate the graph"<<endl;
     cout << "head("<<1<<") is "<< G.head[1]<<endl; 
    cout << "value of head ("<<1<<") is "<< G.head[1]->value<<endl; 
    #endif
        
        
       




return 0;
}
```

Many thanks for your help,
Davide

Comment: `PopulateGraph` promises to return a `AdjVertex*`, but I can't for the life of me see where it keeps that promise.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: `AdjVertex*graph::PopulateGraph(AdjVertex *head,int pos,int size, double P)` says `PopulateGraph` will return a `AdjVertex*`, but when you look at the function there are no `return` statements. `G.head[i]=G.PopulateGraph(G.head[i],i,SIZE,0.5);` is counting on that value that should have been returned but wasn't.

Comment: Many thanks! What if I want to call the function passing the entire G.head (vector of pointers) and not G.head[i], being able to modify the content pointed by the pointer ? Furthermore, is really necessary to return the pointer? Passing the pointer shouldn't be enough to modify the variable inside the function call?